How to marshal/unmarshal struct with agnostic type (interface) in Go?
I have some struct Settings which has an agnostic field Attrs which is a interface.
I have no problem marshaling this with goccy/go-yaml, but I am unsure what the mechanics are to correctly do that?.
The unmarshaling results in:
panic: reflect.Set: value of type map[string]interface {} is not assignable to type ci.Interface [recovered]
        panic: reflect.Set: value of type map[string]interface {} is not assignable to type ci.Interface

I though that creating s2 := S{Attrs: &MyAttrs...} and maybe implementing yaml.InterfaceUnmarshaler (?) for S should be enough to make the library detect that it can unmarshal into Attrs, but that does not work.

package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/goccy/go-yaml"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

type Interface interface {
    Foo()
}

type S struct {
    Type  int       `yaml:"type"`
    Attrs Interface `yaml:"attributes"`
}

type MyAttrs struct {
    MyVal int `yaml:"myVal"`
}

func (a *MyAttrs) Foo() {
    a.MyVal = 101
}

func TestSerialization(t *testing.T) {
    s1 := S{Attrs: &MyAttrs{MyVal: 1}}
    bytes, err := yaml.Marshal(&s1)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    t.Logf("Serialized:\n---\n%s\n---", bytes)

    // Unmarshal
    s2 := S{Attrs: &MyAttrs{MyVal: -1}}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s2)
    require.NoError(t, err)
}



why not use a type alias or a wrapper struct ?
